# 1999 Ford Ranger - Removing head gasket and found mystery coolant line (?) coming out of firewall. What is this?

Tags: ford, coolant, part-identification, ranger

I bought this truck broken and I don't know any of its history other than it has a blown head gasket.

I've tried to be diligent about labeling things and it's possible I labeled this but the tape fell off. It seems a little rough on the end and I'm a little worried it got snapped off? But I imagine if someone snapped it it would be more jagged.

Either way I don't think I removed the hose that goes to it and I'm not sure where that hose would go.

[image: mystery thing]

Comment: Have you accounted for heater hoses?  If there is a similar-sized hose nearby on the firewall it could be a heater hose.

Comment: The heater core would be to the left of pictured above and the 2 hoses would be on the top. The inlet one would the one with the little device attached to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what appears to be a A/C evaporator coil assembly housing based on the large aluminum tube at the top and a smaller one at the bottom. I would say that is the drain hole for the condensation to drain out. No hose required.

Comment: That's a huge relief. I'll mark it as the answer but won't know for sure until I get it all back together. Thanks man.